# How to print out DataSource options (e.g. startingOffsets) for a streaming Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I pass the startingOffsets through a variable . Suspect they might not have the right values . How do i print back to verify the spark structured Streaming options ?

```
val df = sparkSession
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .option("startingOffsets", "{"topic1":{"1":100,"0":120}}")
)
 .load()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print out the extended plan for your streaming Dataframe: `df.explain(true)`.

This will print out your options as shown below:

```
[...]StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@149aa7b2,kafka,List(),None,List(),None,Map(startingOffsets -> {"test":{"0":120}}, failOnDataLoss -> false, subscribe -> test, kafka.bootstrap.servers -> localhost:9092),None), kafka,[...]
```

(Do not get confused, I have used my personal options which means they deviated from what your settings are.)